# Rails Controller Method with if-statement to either render or redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, path, render

Within my rails app, I am trying to create a controller method that depending on an if-statement renders one page or redirects to another path. I figured a solution could be to create a separate method I can call my if-statement that has its individual render. Even though I should fall in the first part of the if-statement the alert.html.erb page view is never displayed. My issue is that Render and redirect are called multiple times in this action (once each). How can I accomplish my method being redirected to different places depending on the if-statement?

```
def alert(url)
    @urls = Url.all
    render :alert
end

def update
    id = params[:id]
    updated_info = params.require(:url).permit(:link, :random_string, :clicks)
    @url = Url.find(id)

    if  not Url.where(random_string: @url.random_string).empty?
        alert(@url)

    end

    @url.update_attributes(updated_info)
    redirect_to edit_url_path(@url.id)
end
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, why did you need separate methods?

Comment: I edited the question so that the "doesn't work" is explained.

Answer (score 0):

add a

```
return
```

immediately after the render or redirect_to

i.e.

```
if [condition A]
  render :edit
  return
elsif [condition B]
  redirect_to my_url
  return
end

redirect_to root_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'return' keyword as:

```
return redirect_to edit_url_path(@url.id)
```

and

```
return normal_path(@url)
```